# How can we solve dynamic pattern program for odd no of values?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, pattern-matching, coding-style

what is the solution of the pattern program given below.
like if we have, n=3 then pattern should be

```
 * 
* *
 *
```

for n=5

```
  * 
 * *
* * *
 * *
  *
```

and so on for n= odd values

Answer (score 0):

here is answer :

### Enter any odd no of your choice

n= int(input("Enter the number:"))

## floor division to divide the pattern into two parts

z= n//2

for i in range(z+1):

```
print(" " *(z-i) + "* " *(i+1))
```

for i in range(z):

```
print(" " *(i+1) + "* " *(z-i))
```